# Can't get simple array to follow curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

For the life of me I can't get this simple array of planes to follow this Bezier curve which runs over a terrain (hidden), this is the closest I could get by adjusting modifier settings. You can see the array kinda follows it but doesn't. Tried replicating in clean blend files and seems to go fine most of the time.

- Bezier curve has no modifiers
- the plane is at the same location as the origin of the Bezier
- tried curve radius points = 1 and with the radius turned off
- all scale rotation etc is applied

Still relatively new so I feel it must be something really silly I've missed but it's had me stumped for ages and I can't figure out how to fix it

Thanks

Blend File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19w7lsuF4uSM4W-IZwPS5gF9PXhM04gMt/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the rotation of the curve, choose *Deform Axis > -x* and maybe rotate the object 90° on X so that it's oriented as you want

Comment: Thanks that worked. I could've sworn on previous attempts I definitely tried applying all scales and rotations, rotating the items, changing the deform axis etct etc but oh well it works now so can't complain!